# execution-order in h:form with h:selectOneMenu, h:outputText and f:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, selectonemenu

i searched a lot about this subject but i didn't find the solution that helps me with my problem.
I have a form that consists of list of "Kategorie"-objects which are placed as selectItems in selectOneMenu and an outputText (uses same bean as selectOneMenu). The converter makes his job and all Kategorie names are shown correctly. With the ajax-tag the form changes the value in selectOneMenu onchange. This also works, the bean-property is updated! But now i want to show the selected Kategorie in an outputText immediatly after change. What do i have to do???

To see the new value in the outputText I have to refresh the page. (KategorieBean is SessionScoped)

The getter of the outputText-value is always called before the Kategorie-property of the bean has been updated.

view.xhtml:

```
    <h:form>
        Wähle eine Kategorie:
        <h:selectOneMenu 
                            value="#{kategorieBean.kategorie}">
            <f:selectItem
                            itemLabel="Wählen..."
                            itemValue="#{null}"/>
            <f:selectItems 
                            value="#{kategorieBean.allKategories}"
                            var="k" 
                            itemLabel="#{k.name}"
                            itemValue="#{k}" />     
            <f:ajax 
                            event="change"
                            execute="@form"
                            render="result"
                            listener="#{kategorieBean.kategorieChangeListener}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        Ausgewählte Kategorie:      
        <h:outputText id="result" value="#{kategorieBean.kategorie.name}" />
    </h:form>
```

I also tried to use a Listener in the ajax-tag. The Listener worked, but I still had the problem with the execution-order :(

KategorieBean:

```
package xxx.bean;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import xxx.hibernate.entity.Kategorie;
import xxx.hibernate.dao.KategorieDao;

@ManagedBean(name="kategorieBean")
@SessionScoped
public class KategorieBean{

private Kategorie kategorie;
private KategorieDao kategorieDao;
private List<Kategorie> allKategories;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    kategorie = null;
    kategorieDao = new KategorieDao();
    allKategories = kategorieDao.getAllKategories();
}

public List<Kategorie> getAllKategories() {
    return allKategories;
}
public void setAllKategories(List<Kategorie> allKategories) {
    this.allKategories = allKategories;
}

public Kategorie getKategorie() {
    if (kategorie != null)
        System.out.println("getter kategorie: name=" + kategorie.getName());
    else
        System.out.println("getter kategorie: kategorie=null");
    return kategorie;
}
public void setKategorie(Kategorie kategorie) {
    System.out.println("setter kategorie: name=" + kategorie.getName());
    this.kategorie = kategorie;
}
    public void kategorieChangeListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
        System.out.println("kategoriename: " + kategorie.getName());
    }
```

KategorieConverter:

```
package xxx.converter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import xxx.bean.KategorieBean;
import xxx.hibernate.entity.Kategorie;

@FacesConverter(forClass = Kategorie.class)
public class KategorieConverter implements Converter{

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        System.out.println("Converter: getAsObject");
        KategorieBean kB = (KategorieBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("kategorieBean");
        for (Kategorie k : kB.getAllKategories()){
            if (k.getKategorieId() == Long.valueOf(value))
                return k;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        System.out.println("Converter: getAsString");
        return String.valueOf(((Kategorie) value).getKategorieId());
    }
}
```

Console output (inital):

- Hibernate: select this_.kategorie_id as kategori1_1_0_,
  this_.beschreibung as beschrei2_1_0_, this_.liferay_company_id as
  liferay3_1_0_, this_.liferay_group_id as liferay4_1_0_, this_.name as
  name5_1_0_, this_.parent_id as parent6_1_0_ from usushop_kategorie
  this_
- getter kategorie: kategorie=null
- Converter: getAsString
- Converter: getAsString
- Converter: getAsString
- Converter: getAsString
- Converter: getAsString
- Converter: getAsString
- getter kategorie: kategorie=null

Console output after value in the selectOneMenu changed:

- Converter: getAsObject
- getter kategorie: kategorie=null
- setter kategorie: name=Kategorie4
- kategoriename: Kategorie4
- getter kategorie: name=Kategorie4

Answer (score 1):

**You can use Richface's a4j(ajax4jsf)**

```
<%@taglib prefix="a4j" uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j"%>



<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{kategorieBean.kategorie}">
            <f:selectItem
                            itemLabel="Wählen..."
                            itemValue="#{null}"/>
            <f:selectItems 
                            value="#{kategorieBean.allKategories}"
                            var="k" 
                            itemLabel="#{k.name}"
                            itemValue="#{k}" />     
            <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{bean.SomeAction}" reRender="result"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
<h:panelGroup id="result">
    <h:outputText  value="#{kategorieBean.kategorie.name}" />
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Comment: or you can use render property of <f:ajax> tag

Comment: thanks!

but I forgot to tell that I will use icefaces in my project. is there also a solution for icefaces?

render property of the <f:ajax> tag doesn't change the execution order :( ... i'm using the liferay-faces-bridge 3.1.1 since i want to write a portlet for liferay

Comment: I dont know abour icefaces :( By the way have you given ID of outputText( that is result) as value of render property?

Comment: And you shoud use <h:head> tag instead of <head> tag

Comment: yes i have given outputText the ID "result" and used in the f:ajax tag the property render="result" ... there is still no change in the execution-order of the getters and setters. and i also used h:head tag. i'm going crazy

Comment: What is the type of kategorie property?? It should be Id of selected item not list. Use that id to get selected item. and have you used richfaces?

Comment: i have added the code of my KategorieBean and my KategorieConverter to my original. kategorie property is an object of Kategorie. i didn't try richfaces because i use icefaces. is it possible to use both?? i don't think that it makes sense to use both

Comment: R u getting changed Kategorie.name value in listener method?

Comment: i tried many different things^^ can't remember of all :( ... now i added again a listener. see my updates in the original post. i also postet the output of the console. i think the changing of the kategorie.name value in the listener method should not be neccesary because the kategorie property of the bean gets updated by selectOneMenu and so the kategorie.name should also be updated

Comment: Im not telling to change the value in listener. Ya bean values are updated.Because in listener method its printing correct value.Print the value kategorie in getter and setter and post it

Comment: i updated the code and postet the console output in the original post

Comment: I've updated my answer. I've added panelgroup tag. Check that out. And try with execute = "result"

Comment: when i try execute="result" the getter method is only called once and the output is null :/

Comment: i will give ace:selectMenu and ace:ajax a try now. but there i have to use a List<SelectItem> and must write another Converter

Comment: Okay try with execute=@form and  Write <h:outputText> inside <h:panelGroup>